# How to redirect IE in php without die()?

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I'm working on a site whith an external webshop like this:

```
$webshopurl = "webshop.com/something/?id=" . $transaction_id; //and some other parameters
header ( "Connection: close" );
header ( "Location: " . $webshopurl );
header ( "Content-Length: " . $length );
$response= getResponse($transaction id /*and some other stuff*/);
```

getResponse() contains a lopp which keeps polling the webshop to see how the transaction went, and reacts accordingly if the transaction is finished, or exits with timeout after 10 minutes. On most browser it works fine, the browser goes to the webshop, the user buys and once the transaction is over the polling loop gets the info and does whatever it does. IE however won't redirect until the PHP stops running, so the loop can't possibly handle the webshop transactions. I tried manually entering the webshop URL into the browser, and everything worked fine.
I didn't write this system, I only maintain it, so I'd rather refrain from the complete overhaul of the system.

EdiT: I tried using javascript and and html meta to redirect, but they only work after the php stopped running

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question is that you need to close the HTTP connection between the PHP program and the browser.

Doing this manually is achieved by sending the following two headers:

```
Connection: close
Content-Length: n (n = size of output in bytes )
```

...followed by flushing the output cache.

The code would look something like this:

```
// send headers to tell the browser to close the connection
header("Content-Length: $contentSize");
header('Connection: close');

// flush all output
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();

// .... PHP code can now continue without the browser caring about it.
```

As you'll notice from the above, you will need to know how big the output is that you've already sent -- this is important; browsers can react badly if you give them an incorrect value here. You can keep a track of it by using the output buffer (`ob_start()`, `ob_flush()`), and checking the size of it with `ob_get_length()`. Not ideal, but probably the best solution. Of course, if all you're doing is a redirect, then you may not be outputting anything to the body, in which case, just give a size of zero.

However...

I would caution against doing this kind of thing. The problem here is that if the program has an error that causes it to never stop running or get into an infinite loop, etc, then doing this will make that kind of bug very very difficult to track down. You may not even know about it until your server starts slowing down or refusing connections for no apparent reason.

I would suggest that you would be much better off handling the long-term processing in an entirely separate process thread. The way I'd do it would be to do the polling using a small short-lived PHP program that is fired from a cron-job. This will keep running the program over and over at a set interval behind the scenes, with no connection to the end user or their browser.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So ob_start(), ob_end_flush(), etc was already in place and $length came from ob_get_length(), I just didn't realize their importance. I'd rather not mess too much with a system that is already working  (mostly), so I'd avoid completely redoing it and moving it into a cron-job. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a callback url if the API of the webshop lets you send one, and put the code to be run after success there instead of keeping a process loop running on your server that might never terminate. If the callback url is not available, then a cron-job is the way to go, that uses one process for all the checks, instead of having one thread for every transaction that didn't terminate yet.